# Spring rabbit: Intercept method calls annotated with @RabbitListener without AspectJ usage

Tags: spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Is there a way to intercept calls of bean methods annotated with  @RabbitListener without using AspectJ.

The code is something like this

```
@OtherAnnotation
@RabbitListener
public void do(Message message)
```

I need to intercept all calls to @RabbitListener method, if the method has @OtherAnnotation annotation.

**UPDATE:**

I managed to make it work using Gary Russell solution.

```
public class CustomRabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor extends RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    protected void processAmqpListener(RabbitListener rabbitListener, final Method method, Object bean, String beanName) {
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(OtherAnnotation.class)) {
            ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory(bean);
            proxyFactory.addAdvisor(new StaticMethodMatcherPointcutAdvisor(new OtherAnnotationInterceptor()) {
               @Override
               public boolean matches(Method advisorMethod, Class<?> targetClass) {
                  return advisorMethod.equals(method);
               }
            });
            Object proxiedBean = proxyFactory.getProxy();
            super.processAmqpListener(rabbitListener, method, proxiedBean, beanName);
        } else {
            super.processAmqpListener(rabbitListener, method, bean, beanName);
        }
    }
}
```

The bean definition is like:

```
    @Bean(name = RabbitListenerConfigUtils.RABBIT_LISTENER_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME)
    public CustomRabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor customRabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new CustomRabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }
```

It's a bit ugly, but it works. If anyone has better solution, please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and override the `processListener` method and modify the bean before invoking the super version.

Then, replace the `RabbitListenerConfigUtils.RABBIT_LISTENER_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME` bean registered by the `@EnableRabbit` with your subclass.

<del>Or, simply add your advice to the container factory's advice chain and all listeners will be advised. You can then do a runtime check to see if the other annotation is present.</del>

Comment: cannot add it to advice chain, since the pointcut for advice chain is on `public abstract void org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$ContainerDelegate.invokeListener` method, and not on the method annotated with `@RabitListener`

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry - that advice runs before the message is converted.

Comment: I updated my question with solution using your first approach. It's a bit ugly, but it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

i think what you are looking for is a [bean-post-processor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html)

heres a simple example: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_post_processors.htm

if you need to intercept calls you can wrap a proxy over the returned instance. a good example is the org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor. you can probably extend org.springframework.aop.framework.AbstractAdvisingBeanPostProcessor as well.

---

EDIT i am just learning this myself so i hope that is the right way to do this but this worked for me when experimenting with it

```
@Component
public class MyInterceptAnnotationBeanPostProcessor 
    extends AbstractBeanFactoryAwareAdvisingPostProcessor
    implements InitializingBean {

    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        AnnotationMatchingPointcut pointcut = new AnnotationMatchingPointcut(
                null,
                MyIntercept.class);
        this.advisor = new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, this.createAdvice());
    }

    protected Advice createAdvice() {
        return new MethodInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public Object invoke(MethodInvocation arg0) throws Throwable {
                System.out.println("advice");
                return arg0.proceed();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks like a good approach, but a method annotated with @RabitListener is called from SimpleMessageListenerContainer using AOP proxy, and for that reason other annotations on the method are ignored

Comment: your code works fine when used on any Spring bean, but when used with RabitListener /SimpleMessageListenerContainer it does not work. You can try it your self. Create a configuration with `@EnableRabbit`, a bean with method annotated with both `@RabbitListener` and `@YourCustomAnnotation` and send a message to that rabbitListener. The interceptor for `@YourCustomAnnotaion` is not going to be executed. Thanks for your help, anyway.